# How to resolve conflicts when using git?

Tags: xcode, git, git-rebase

I'm trying to rebase...you can read all about my trials [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8780257/201381).
I'm working on an XCode project and after I've performed a `get rebase master my_branch`, I get messages about conflicts. I'm trying to resolve them. The text files are easy. There are also some XCode config files, that I basically want to keep and don't need any manual resolution.

So...after I've resolved the conflicts in my source files what do I do? Is there a way to mark the files as resolved? Do I commit them to the local repo? Or do I just do a `git rebase --continue`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark a file as "resolved" by `git add`ing that file. After that, you can do a `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Oh I see. Add the files to the index and then `git rebase --continue` is the command that will act on those files? Thanks!

Comment: The index is the data structure that assembles the next commit. If an operation that involves creating a commit requires human intervention,   what git is asking you to do is to manually assemble something into the index. You do this using the `add` command.