# Using git, how do a merge a tracked branch back into the remote origin/HEAD?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I got myself into a little bit of a local repo mess. [Long story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780257/git-rebase-a-branch-onto-master-failed-how-to-resolve) short, I had a copy of a remote repo; I created a branch called 'my_branch' in my local repo; I committed work a few times. I then just pushed the branch to the remote repo. Here's my local repo diagram...(since I've pushed my_branch to the remote, this is what remote looks like too).

```
--C0--------------C4--  (local master) 
      \
       --C1-C2-C3--     (local my_branch)
```

I then decided to try to rebase, but I think I totally messed up. I also tried to do `git reset --hard` and I think I corrupted my local repo some more. So I decided to start from a clean place. I grabbed my_branch from the remote repo [following this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146786/201381).

I then checked out origin/my_branch from remote. (I now see that I have a "detached HEAD" in my GUI tool GitX.) Now...how do I merge this branch with origin/HEAD aka origin/master on remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a branch right where you are to get that work tracked

```
git checkout -b new-branch HEAD
```

Now you can check out other branches and merge or rebase them.

To get a local branch for a remote one that you are not tracking yet:

```
git checkout -t origin/some-branch
```

Now just push up the branches. Most likely you will require a force push

```
git push -f origin some-branch
```

Comment: Just to see if I understand this...so for me I would do a `git checkout -t origin/my_branch` (this would checkout a local tracked version of my_branch. Then when I do a `git push -f origin my_branch` that would ask git to try to merge my_branch local and origin?

Comment: No. When you push, you are just changing a pointer to a particular commit. No merging occurs here.